# TSQL - varchar max column does not contain set of strings in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
TableA  
(  
    id int identity(1,1),  
    maxString varchar(max)  
)
```

and

```
TableB  
(  
    id int identity(1,1),  
    excludeString varchar(3072)  
)
```

Sample Data in TableA

```
|Id | maxString               |
|1  | abcdef \n ijk \n lmn \n |    --\n is a new line character  
|2  | nvc \n tre \n           |
```

Sample data in TableB

```
|Id | excludeString |    
|1  | ijk           |
```

Q. I want to select rows from TableA which does not have tableb "excludestring"

In the example, the result should be a 2nd row in tableA becuase it does not contain "ijk"

`select * from TableA where maxstring does not contain (select excludestring from TableB).....`

```
|Id | maxString     |
|2  | nvc \n tre \n |
```

Comment: Please format your question to be readable.

Comment: And what part of that are you having a problem with?

Comment: SInce it is a varchar(Max) column, am looking for a performant query

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT TableA.*
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON 1=1
WHERE TableA.maxString NOT LIKE '%' + TableB.excludeString + '%'
```